# Outlook 2010 or Exchange is sending plain text when it should send HTML. Why?

Tags: email, exchange, formatting, outlook-2010

If I open the saved .msg file I see the following:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version 6.5.7654.12">
<TITLE>Henry Jacobs &amp; Associates Appt</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/plain format -->
```

Why would this be happening if the email is composed in HTML format and should be sent as such? I assume the above means that MS Exchange Server is modifying the message.

After the message is sent it appears correctly in the users Sent Items folder, additionally if it is sent to another exchange user it keeps the correct formatting. However, if the message is sent to an email address that is not internal to the exchange server then the message appears as plain text instead of html formatted.

Comment: And this is a problem?!?! IMHO email should only ever be plain text. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What version of Exchange are you running?  You may have configured your Internet connector to force outbound email to text/plain.  You may also want to check your contacts.  You can set a preferred format in your contact records.

How to configure Internet e-mail message formats at the user and the domain levels in Exchange Server 2003 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821750

Comment: In the headers of the code we can see: CONTENT="MS Exchange Server version 6.5.7654.12", 6.5 = Exchange 2003

Comment: Right, so the kb I mentioned is the correct one for you.  Check to how your Exchange server is configured.